# Problem with disappearing shadow in Eevee

Tags: lighting, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a problem with disappearing shadow in Eevee. When object (head) is moving the shadow behind it is disappearing like on the picture. I thought it's about the bloom but it's not. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'd say it follows the head's movement in the right direction.

Comment: It looks like it's related to the Contact Shadows. Try to adjust it in the Light settings/Shadows/Contact Shadows.

Comment: @Jackdaw It's probably related with Shadow but can't figure out how. Even if I turn off the Contact Shadows the problem still exist with shadow. Light is Sun. I tried to change every parameter in light's shadow setup but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Do you mind sharing the file?

Comment: @Jackdaw Here it is: [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b9dee86fc442802a35f3a72bc3c59fd120190801131035/cc85cf279420cbe46421f204e38481e920190801131035/2f41b6]

Comment: I can confirm that it is the Contact Shadows. How to solve it is another problem. I would try to have the background rendered separately and compose it together with the baby or to render it with Cycles instead.

Comment: @Jackdaw Using Cycles is not a solution - I want it work properly in Eevee, not using other engine. Rendering background separately is an option (and probably I use it if I don't figure out anything else) but still it will be much better if this works properly without tricks like this. Anyways thanks for the advices :)

Comment: You may get a bit better result if you set the shadow softness to zero and increase the Sun Lamps Angle to 10 degrees. You can also lower the Shadow bias to something like 0.25. Ambient occlusion can also be a problem on these scenes. Only use a very short Contact shadow.

Comment: @Jackdaw After some more tests I figure out that is have nothing to do with lamp on the scene. After deleting it the problem still exist. Seems that it is definitely something with ambient occlusion. Probably adjust some settings here should resolve the problem.

Comment: Changing Distance (making it bigger) in Ambient Occlusion setup fix the problem but unfortunately it makes big shadow on the wall behind the head. I think this is some kind of error of the engine itself but still have hope someone know how to set it properly.